# Magento Shipping method stops working after ALTER tables 'sales_flat_quote_address' and 'sales_flat_order_address'

Tags: magento

I had ALTER tables 'sales_flat_quote_address' and 'sales_flat_order_address' to add a new column in order to add a custom field in Billing and Shipping process. But after doing that even the default shipping method stops working and it is not still not working after drop of  this column. Below is the code I had used in my sql file of my module.

```
    $installer = $this;

    $installer->startSetup();

     /* @var $addressHelper Mage_Customer_Helper_Address */
    $addressHelper = Mage::helper('customer/address');
    $store         = Mage::app()->getStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    /* @var $eavConfig Mage_Eav_Model_Config */
    $eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');

    // update customer address user defined attributes data
    $attributes = array(
        'suburb'           => array(   
            'label'    => 'Suburb',
            'type'     => 'varchar',
            'input'    => 'text',
            'is_user_defined'   => 1,
            'is_system'         => 0,
            'is_visible'        => 1,
            'sort_order'        => 140,
            'is_required'       => 1,
            'multiline_count'   => 0,
            'validate_rules'    => array(
                'max_text_length'   => 255,
                'min_text_length'   => 1
            ),
        ),
    );

    foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode => $data) {
        $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode);
        $attribute->setWebsite($store->getWebsite());
        $attribute->addData($data);
            $usedInForms = array(
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address'
            );
            $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
        $attribute->save();
    }

    $installer->run("
        ALTER TABLE {$installer->getTable('sales_flat_quote_address')} ADD COLUMN suburb VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL AFTER fax;
        ALTER TABLE {$installer->getTable('sales_flat_order_address')} ADD COLUMN suburb VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL AFTER fax;


        ");     

    $installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

by fiddling with shipping options I noticed it may stop checkout (not loading shipping methods) but it thows fatal error. Enable logging in your backend, then navigate to your checkout and try selecting everything up to non-working shipping method. when this is done, check your exception log, and var/reports folder. these may give you some information what has gone wrong in your particular case.